# Проблема с hover и активной ссылкой в нём

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, я решил сделать сайт по шаблону от wix.com, я только учусь, вот не могу понять как сделать так что бы блок с картинкой заливался желтым с `opacity 0.6` где-то и в то же время что бы эта картинка была ссылкой на саму себя но в окне галереи от fancybox.
У меня заливка желтым уже стоит через `hover`, но картинка не работает как ссылка, если я убираю `hover`, то ссылка становится активной и галерея работает как задумано.

[Вот ссылка на шаблон сайта](http://ru.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1642?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F2&bookName=&galleryDocIndex=7&category=all)

Вкладка "О нас", внизу есть фото команды, они при наведении на них мышкой заливаются желтым, а блок с текстом нет, у меня это работает, но не работает ссылка в картинке на галерею как в оригинальном шаблоне.

Вот код:

```css
.im {
  width: 240px;
  height: 198px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}
.im:hover {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: yellow;
  content: " ";
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
div:hover .im:after {
  opacity: .6;
}
.emp1,
.empinfo1 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.emp1 {
  font-family: play, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 230.2px;
  height: 29px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td id="td1">
    <div id="line1block7">
      <div class="im">
        <a class="gallery" rel="group" href="images/com_1big.jpg" width="240px" height="198px">
          <img src="images/com_1.jpg" width="240px" height="198px">
        </a>
      </div>
      <span class="emp1">Юлия Соколова</span><span class="empinfo1"><p class="text1">Руководитель студии<br><br>Это текст. Кликните дважды, чтобы отредактировать его. Расскажите посетителям сайта о себе, своих услугах и преимуществах.</p></span>
  </td>
  </div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, а то я буду ещё недели две сидеть над этим пунктом.

Comment: Вроде работает ссылка..

Comment: ссылка дана на оригинальный шаблон от wix, у меня на сайте ссылка не работает если есть hover, когда убираю hover то ссылка становится рабочей

Comment: Ну как так может быть, что из за стиля ссылка не работает?

Comment: да я вот и понимаю что из-за него, как сделать так что бы работал и стиль и ссылка, что изменить в коде то нужно?

Comment: Ну не может ссылка не работать из за стиля. Попробуйте в `.im:hover` убрать `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.im:hover {
  opacity: 0; **/*Это говорит что при наведении на im он станет полностью прозрачным (т.е. невидимым)*/**
}
div:hover .im:after {
 
  opacity: .6; **/*В данном случае применение прозрачности применяется к псевдоклассу after который у вас нигде не обозначен в предоставленном коде, причем применяется только при наведении на div*/**
 
}
**Скорее всего у вас ошибка здесь** `.im:hover {` наверное должно быть `.im:after {` и при указании положения элемента достаточно двух показателей, к примеру  `top: 0; left: 0;` если хотите центрировать элемент, то для этого используется margin

Answer (score 1):

В принципе , сам блок с изображением `relative` и на него абсолютным позиционированием другой блок , можно просто с любым цветом и `opacity`, вот пример 
Если я вдруг не понял суть вопроса напишите и я доделаю

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.card {
  width: 240px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.images_container {
  position: relative;
}
.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}
.card:hover .yellow {
  background: red;
  opacity: .2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text p:first-child {
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.text p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: italic;
}
.text p:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="images_container">
    <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/11d79d_b224ea3b545a4d6cb2e6d468e2558814.jpg/v1/fill/w_441,h_383,al_c,q_90,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/11d79d_b224ea3b545a4d6cb2e6d468e2558814.webp" alt="">
    <div class="yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Тамара Миронова</p>
    <p>Менеджер по работе с клиентами</p>
    <p>Это текст. Кликните дважды, чтобы отредактировать его. Расскажите посетителям сайта о себе, своих услугах и преимуществах.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: можно проще сделать данный эффект без создания лишних классов

Comment: @Юрий    я в курсе ...

Answer (score 0):

Всё, вчера разобрался с кодом, всё заработало как надо, спасибо всем за помощь, без вас бы не разобрался скорее всего) Вот рабочий код, может кому пригодится:

```css
.im{
 width: 240px;
 height: 198px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border: none;
 background: yellow;
 
}
.im:hover .gallery{
    transition:all .5s;
    background: yellow;
    content: " ";

}
div:hover .gallery{
    transition:all .5s;
    background: yellow;
    content: " ";
    opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<div id="line1block7">
<div class="im"> <a class="gallery" rel="group" href="images/com_1big.jpg" width="240px" height="198px"><img src="images/com_1.jpg" width="240px" height="198px"></a></div>
<span class="emp1">Юлия Соколова</span><span class="empinfo1"><p class="text1">Руководитель студии<br><br>Это текст. Кликните дважды, чтобы отредактировать его. Расскажите посетителям сайта о себе, своих услугах и преимуществах.</p></span>
</td>
</div>
```